# Getting 2 related groups with 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I've got the following scenario:

- 1 item table
- 1 member table
- 1 page table

Each "item" belongs to a "member" and a "page"

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT i.id, i.title, mem.realname, p.pagename
                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN members AS mem ON (mem.ID_MEMBER = i.author)
                LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON (p.id = i.page)
                WHERE i.id LIKE '$item_id'");
```

This gives the basic info which I need:

- id: 3, title: Music video, realname: Peter Smith, pagename: Youtube

So what I'm going for is to get 2 separate groups of "3 related items" where:

- id.author = Peter Smith
- id.page = Youtube

So output would be something like this:

- id: 3, title: Music video, realname: Peter Smith, pagename: Youtube
- items from Peter Smith: item 5, item 4, item 8 (randomly displayed)
- items from Youtube: item 1, item 2, item 9 (randomly displayed)

Do I need to perform 2 additional queries to get this info? Or can I pack it in all one query?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:**

I added a Group_concat suggested by @valex

```
   SELECT i.id, i.title, mem.realname, p.pagename,
          ( select CONCAT('Items from ', mem.realname,': ',
                (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                        FROM
                           (Select Title from items where author=
                                    (select author from items 
                                              WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1)
                             ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                )
           ) as items_from_author,
          ( select CONCAT('Items from ',p.pagename,': ',
                (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                        FROM
                           (Select Title from items where page=
                                        (select page from items 
                                              WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1)

                             ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                )
           ) as items_from_page


            FROM items AS i
            LEFT JOIN members AS mem ON (mem.ID_MEMBER = i.author)
            LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON (p.id = i.page)
            WHERE i.id LIKE '$item_id'
```

But get the following error:

```
Invalid query: Unknown column 'i.author' in 'where clause'
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

Currently using "4 level" query suggested by @valex. Is there a way to make it work with 2 levels?

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, mem.realname, p.pagename,
          ( select CONCAT('Items from ', mem.realname,': ',
                (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                        FROM
                           (Select Title from items where author=
                                    (select author from items 
                                              WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1)
                             ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                )
           ) as items_from_author,
          ( select CONCAT('Items from ',p.pagename,': ',
                (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                        FROM
                           (Select Title from items where page=
                                        (select page from items 
                                              WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1)

                             ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                )
           ) as items_from_page


            FROM items AS i
            LEFT JOIN members AS mem ON (mem.ID_MEMBER = i.author)
            LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON (p.id = i.page)
            WHERE i.id LIKE '$item_id'
```

Seems like this could be optimized somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to get these lists as a fields in the current row.

For example:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, mem.realname, p.pagename,
              ( select CONCAT('Items from ', mem.realname,': ',
                    (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                            FROM
                               (Select Title from items where author=i.author
                                 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                    )
               ) as items_from_author,
              ( select CONCAT('Items from ',p.pagename,': ',
                    (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                            FROM
                               (Select Title from items where page=i.page
                                 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                    )
               ) as items_from_page


                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN members AS mem ON (mem.ID_MEMBER = i.author)
                LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON (p.id = i.page)
                WHERE i.id LIKE '$item_id'
```

Update: It seems that MySQL can't access an outer query field through two levels. So try to use the following:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, mem.realname, p.pagename,
              ( select CONCAT('Items from ', mem.realname,': ',
                    (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                            FROM
                               (Select Title from items where author=
                                        (select author from items 
                                                  WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1)
                                 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                    )
               ) as items_from_author,
              ( select CONCAT('Items from ',p.pagename,': ',
                    (select GROUP_CONCAT(Title) 
                            FROM
                               (Select Title from items where page=
                                            (select page from items 
                                                  WHERE id = '$item_id' LIMIT 1)

                                 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) T)              
                    )
               ) as items_from_page


                FROM items AS i
                LEFT JOIN members AS mem ON (mem.ID_MEMBER = i.author)
                LEFT JOIN pages AS p ON (p.id = i.page)
                WHERE i.id LIKE '$item_id'
```

Comment: Looks promising. I did get error message though: Invalid query: Unknown column 'i.author' in 'where clause'

Comment: That works.... but is adding a 3rd level the most optimal solution? seems a bit too much.